# Facebook does not show correct installs

Tags: facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have integrated the facebook module (version 4.0.5) into Appcelerator app, but I only need statistics (no login, no social activity)
So I just added the module with app id and that's it. 
However, the number of installs showing up in FB statistics is incorrect, like very incorrect - 1 install on Facebook against 30-50 installs registered by each shop. 
We checked everything - the number of new registered users also corresponds to the shop statistics. 
Any idea what could be the problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: How do you expect to get installs without login? “Installing” an app in Facebook terms literally _is_ logging in to it for the first time.

Comment: Are you sure? What if the user does not have a fb account or does not want to log in? I thought app id (the one from Facebook) is sufficient

Comment: Besides how do you actually measure INSTALLS, if FB login may or may not come time later?

Comment: You don’t. The first login is counted as an installation, and nothing else.

Comment: Okay... thank you.... that would explain it...

Comment: Could this be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798237/facebook-installs-tracking-for-android perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: It was related to a bug in Appcelerator Ti.Facebook module, as Fokke correctly commented above.

With a fix it works

https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/pull/37