# Facebook installs tracking for Android

Tags: facebook, appcelerator, facebook-android-sdk, appcelerator-titanium

We are still in process of investigation, why our installs do not get tracked. I have opened another support ticket with Facebook to clarify if install and login are equal or different events, but I also want to dig more into the Ti.Facebook module. We've been testing on Android because of the ease of updates.

This is the explanation on Facebook SDK, what needs to be done, to track installs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk#install-tracking

And this is the code to log in installs in Android:

```
protected void onResume() { 
  super.onResume(); 
  AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this); 
}
```

I searched all over Ti.Facebook module, and I have not found a call to AppEventsLogger.activateApp

Can it be a bug or is there some other way to activate the logger first time upon install?

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/automatic-event-collection-detail, "the app install event is triggered the first time a new user activates an app." However, you need to have Facebook SDK for Andoroid v4.19 (or higher).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there indeed this is only [implemented for iOS](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/blob/master/ios/Classes/FacebookModule.m#L66) and not for Android. You could create a [JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org) ticket at the Appcelerator JIRA to report this as a bug.

If you link to this question Appcelerator will understand the reference, and link the JIRA ticket here, so others can also follow this ticket for progress.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this bug and submitted pull request to Ti.Facebook module. We have published a release to check it, it´s there since yesterday afternoon and it works correctly now for our startup.

Pull request:
https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/pull/37