# How to track installs in Facebook Analytics?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-analytics

In numeral 4 at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk#install-tracking ("Enable Install Tracking"), they say "To enable install tracking call the App Events logger once your application becomes active.". However, I implemented the following line successfully, but it does not seem to be tracking installs:

`AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);`

In the Facebook Analytics for Apps reports, I see that the activateApp() method is "App Launches"/, not "App Installs". How can I track installs in Facebook Analytics?

Comment: I meant to say: " the activateApp() method is tracking "App Launches", not "App Installs".

Comment: I see a related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798237/facebook-installs-tracking-for-android, but what would be the solution?

Comment: According to the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AppEventsLogger/, "activateApp(Application) notifies the events system that the app has launched". From what I understand, it does not track app installs but app launches. If that is the case, how can I track app installs?

Comment: I am using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/ and after I choose my app, in the "Android Setup" section with instructions about the configuration to see "installs over the last 7 days", I see this: "Call the 'activateApp' function as soon as the app is on foreground." According to that information, I guess activateApp() could be used to track. But I see it is only reporting App Launches, not App Installs.

Comment: From my observations while testing, the activateApp() method corresponds to the fb_mobile_activate_app event. I can confirm that from the information at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/v2.8 in the "App Event Schema" section. In the "Notes", it says: "Use this event in addition to install reporting." So I guess what is really needed to track installs is to follow the instructions from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/v2.8#installs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SDK >= 4.19 we simplified the track of installs (New Users metric) and activate app (App Launches metric). One should just make sure ApplicationManifest.xml is correctly configured and simply bundle our Android SDK to the App. The SDK will be auto initialized and both install event and activate app will be sent.
More details can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/automatic-event-collection-detail

Comment: I am using Facebook SDK 3.23.1. I was examining the details at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/automatic-event-collection-detail, and I see it is required to have Facebook SDK for Andoroid v4.19 (or higher). Do you know if I have an alternative with SDK 3.23.1 to track installs in Facebook Analytics, or is my only option to upgrade?

Comment: Your only option is to upgrade to the latest Facebook SDK.